# How to fix Runtime error in my C++ script

Tags: c++, runtime-error

My code tries to check if there is a solution to unknown value n in this equation:
*x1 + n*v1 = x2 + n*v2*
with given inputs x1, v1, x2, v2 with input for **x1 v1 x2 v2**. So that I can tell "YES" if there is a value that meets in the same value for both sides of the equation.

**n** is addressed as **output** in my code.

For curious here is the problem [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kangaroo/problem)

```
string kangaroo(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2) {
    string output;
    int x3;
    int v3;

    x3 = x1-x2;
    v3 = v2-v1;

    int div = x3/v3;
    int remain = x3%v3;

    if(div > 0 && remain == 0){
        output = "YES";
    }else{
        output = "NO";

    }

    return output;
}
```

My code works but it raises runtime error where x1 v1 x2 v2 are 43 2 70 2 which is too big for my solution. I am asking what possible improvements can be implemented for my case?

### here is my resolution to this problem

```
if(x1<x2 && v1<v2){
       return "NO";
   }else{
       if(v1!=v2 && ((x2-x1)%(v1-v2)==0)){
           return "YES";
       }else{
           return "NO";
       }
   }
```

**As a result:**

**1.** check if x1,x2 and v1,v2 values are creating any unwanted result
    (x1-x2 and v1-v2 are negative then this is unwanted)

**2.**   check for divider not be zero (if v1 != v2, no divide by zero
    situation)

Regards.

Comment: What do you hope will happen when your program attempts division by zero?  With your given input, `v3` is `0` in `int remain = x3%v3;`

Comment: you must refine your approach: before computing x3/v3 you must check if v3=0 (which means v1=v2). In that case you have x3=x1-x2=n.0 which has no solution if x1!=x2 and an infinite number of solutions otherwise (for any integer n you have 0=n.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving `runtime_error` which indicates this error can only be detected during runtime.

```
int div = x3/v3;
```

Here you have to make sure v3 is not zero.

Comment: That won't work. Next time please try to debug the code first. In this case, the error is clear. It happens with v1 and v2 are both 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should study math, linear algebra, in more detail. For v1 = v2, any value of these variables will result in a runtime error because you will be dividing by zero.

The system of equations is unsolvable for v1 = v2 case.